# Trying to populate an alias column where X = 1, multiple joins, sub-query

Tags: mysql

I have the query below which returns all of the columns I am expecting. However, the date_met column is seeming to return a.) the same date for all results and b.) the wrong date for any results. It looks like it's really just picking the most current date in the date_start column, considering it's putting 2016-11-06, which is a valid date_start, but it's outside of the main queries BETWEEN...

I am utterly terrible at sub-queries, so I'm unsure where exactly I'm going wrong:

```
SELECT 
    the_thresholds.client_id,
    the_thresholds.zipcode,
    ziplatlongs.county,
    ziplatlongs.city,
    ziplatlongs.stateabbr,
    the_thresholds.email,
    the_thresholds.threshold_snow AS snow_threshold,
    SUM(certifications.total_snow) AS rollingTotal,
    SUM(certifications.total_snow) >= the_thresholds.threshold_snow AS targetMet,
    IF(SUM(certifications.total_snow) >= the_thresholds.threshold_snow,
        MIN(certifications.date_start),
    0) AS dateMet
FROM
    `customer_settings`.`snowfall_thresholds` AS the_thresholds
        INNER JOIN
    `snowfall_certification`.`the_certifications` AS certifications ON `the_thresholds`.`zipcode` = `certifications`.`zipcode`
        INNER JOIN
    `zipcodes`.`ziplatlongs` AS ziplatlongs ON `the_thresholds`.`zipcode` = `ziplatlongs`.`zipcode`
WHERE
    DATE(`certifications`.`date_start`) BETWEEN '2015-10-01' AND '2016-05-31'
GROUP BY `the_thresholds`.`zipcode`
```

As I said, it's returning all of the columns I expect, I just can't get it to put the correct dateMet where the threshold was reached.

Comment: Your group by has a number of columns by inforiore to those selected in the selected columns value not present in the first group by and the select is not corrisponte to that of the row with the aggregate value

Comment: I added an Example 2 to the dupe close question and answer of mine on it. Hopefully it illustrates the near randomness / gibberish / snafu data that one can expect when `group by` is used in a manner that doesn't make sense to anyone.

Comment: And what MySQL did by allowing a ton of years of non-conformity to the standard was to unleash a monster in the form of allowable SQL that may have been returning faulty data for years.

Comment: Well to be fair, to a newbie, if you wanted to SUM a column, and then just group the SUMed column by another column 'makes sense', from a logical standpoint. From a real-world, how GROUP BY works, sure maybe not. Particularly to visual learners like myself where reading a manual doesn't work too well.